# Leading Zero's in int returning weird number c++

Tags: c++

I'm doing UTs on a class of mine, and I tried the edge case of putting 05421 in the ctor instead of 5421.

As far as I know, putting a leading zero in an integer results an octal number, but seeing as iy returns 2833 as the number, it's not octal.

Anyone knows what's going on behind the scenes here?

Comment: 5421 in octal *is* 2833...

Comment: Is this a game development question?

Comment: No. My task is to create a class that can hold an "infinite number". I use a vector to hold the numbers (each cell is one digit), and a bool to hold the sign. I have a ctor for string, int and char. Edit - I just realized I posted on gamedev. My bad 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting a literal number (that is, a number written down in your source code) with a zero does indeed mean it will be interpreted as an octal number.

However, this does not carry any further than the interpretation of that one number. It does not store a flag next to the variable saying "This number was once octal, represent it as such", it just goes "Hey! A number, I can represent this." and shows the base-10 representation of that number.

Your IDE may have an option to show its numbers in different bases, I know visual studio has the option to show numbers in base 16 (hexadecimal).

And note, as congusbonugs said: `2833 == 05421` (1 + 2*8 + 4*8*8 + 5*8*8*8 = 2833)

Comment: Ok, I kinda messed up how I understood. Thanks for the answer

Comment: No problem :). It's one of those little things you don't think about beyond "This means it's an octal number"... "Wait how is there an 8 in an octal number?"

Comment: Exactly my point haha